# Update multiple tables in one Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

I have three tables A, B, C.  Table B & Table C consist foreign key from table A's id.

When updating Form, data will be updated  to these three tables by identifying the foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE A(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY, 
   id_theme_thesaurus  text,
   id_series text,
   id_geo_form text
);

CREATE  TABLE B(
   id  serial PRIMARY KEY,
   meta_id int,
   cit_title text,
   cit_pub_date text
);

CREATE  TABLE C(
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   meta_id int,
   id_originator text
);
```

And here is my update statement

```
UPDATE B AS c
SET cit_pub_date = '2016'
FROM t_metadata AS m
WHERE c.meta_id = m.id
AND m.id = '2';

UPDATE C AS o
SET id_originator = 'UN'
FROM t_metadata AS m
WHERE o.meta_id = m.id
AND m.id = '2';
```

How can I join these two UPDATE statements to become one in the join?

Comment: Are you asking to update both tables in single update query ?

Comment: yes, to update both tables in single update query.

Comment: update query can be used only for single table. however whats the issue having 2 update statements ? The solution you are looking can be achieved through CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CTE(with clause) could help to solve your problem, it would implement that update two tables in just one sql. As below:

```
with tmp1 as (
UPDATE B AS c SET cit_pub_date = '2016' FROM t_metadata AS m WHERE c.meta_id = m.id AND m.id = '2'
)
,tmp2 as (
UPDATE C AS o SET id_originator = 'UN' FROM t_metadata AS m WHERE o.meta_id = m.id AND m.id = '2' returning o.meta_id
)
select * from tmp2
```